# Stata: Reverse Sort

Tags: stata

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
id varA  varB   varC
1   0     10    .
1   0     20    .
1   0     35    .
2   1     60    76
2   1     76    60 
2   0     32    .
```

I want to create the varC that reverses the order of varB only for the values varA=1 and missing otherwise.

Comment: Is this really reverse sorting, or is it a matter of giving pairs of observations the other observation's values? See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0043

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nick. I believe that this document applies to the cases when we already have another variable that defines the pairing i.e. VarC in this case. However,  I don't have the varC and I want to create it based on varB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
clear 
input id varA  varB   varC
1   0     10    .
1   0     20    .
1   0     35    .
2   1     60    76
2   1     76    60 
2   0     32    .
end 

gen group = sum(id != id[_n-1] | varA != varA[_n-1])
sort group, stable 
by group: gen wanted = cond(varA == 1, varB[_N - _n + 1], .)

list id var* wanted, sepby(id varA) 

     +----------------------------------+
     | id   varA   varB   varC   wanted |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. |  1      0     10      .        . |
  2. |  1      0     20      .        . |
  3. |  1      0     35      .        . |
     |----------------------------------|
  4. |  2      1     60     76       76 |
  5. |  2      1     76     60       60 |
     |----------------------------------|
  6. |  2      0     32      .        . |
     +----------------------------------+
```